# KeepassXC: command to open local server and then a specific firefox profile and url

Tags: command-line, arch-linux, url, keepassxc

I am running Arch linux.

I am trying to run two applications in the URL: field within KeepassXC.

I want to open the Openrefine server, which I can do using

```
cmd://openrefine
```

but I also want to open a url within a specific browser profile which, I can do separately using

```
cmd://firefox -P "MyProfile" "http://127.0.0.1:3333/"
```

How would I combine these within the url field? I've tried a number of methods without success.

If possible I would like a pause of ~2 seconds before the firefox profile is opened but will settle for not having that if it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this via a shell script. I could successfully make KeePassXC execute a script as follows :

create a file :

```bash
touch $HOME/bin/my-script
```

make it executable :

```bash
chmod a+x $HOME/bin/my-script
```

add your commands to the my-script file (don't hesitate to adapt the shebang) :

```bash
#!/bin/bash
openrefine &
sleep 2
firefox -P "MyProfile" "http://127.0.0.1:3333/" &
```

provide KeePassXC with the URL:

```
cmd:///home/<user>/bin/my-script
```